# Possible bug in iOS app: showing wrong message count

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Screenshot]

These 4 messages that are shown were read at least four times. Restarting the app doesn't help as the badge keeps appearing. When I read these messages, the badge disappears, then, after s few seconds, it appears again. It's also present on the app's icon.

[image: Icon]

Apple iPhone 6+ iOS 8.4

**Update**: since I've just participated in some discussions, I got three more comments. Now I've got *seven* (!) 'unread' messages

**Update**: this should be a problem with the app as whether I read these messages or not, this badge is still present on the SO site. When I read these messages using the site (for the tenth time!) the badge disappears and pops up only when I get new messages.

That's really annoying: I'm used to the badge showing the unread messages count but now it went absolutely crazy. I see that I have lots of unread messages and then realize that they're read already. It's very easy to miss some important messages if you stop paying attention to this badge. And that's the thing this bug forces me to do.

Comment: After almost two hours I'm unable to get rid of this banner... WTF?

Comment: Similar report on MSE for the [android-app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256446/inbox-items-not-marked-read)

Comment: This happened to me as well, however after checking the notification on the website/app and then closing the app (double click home button/swipe up) I was able to get it to go away. It did reappear 3 times though after checking.

Comment: Getting a similar behavior here, where one unread message will not stay read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is fixed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256472/235711)

The core team has been reworking the inbox code and there have been some unexpected side effects.  If it's still happening, comment on this answer and then I'll be stuck with a notification too. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it works as a charm now